# How can i know that my dataset is being well distributed with K-means?

Tags: k-means, anomaly-detection, spark-mllib

I'm trying to make an anomaly detection system using Spark Mlib an its K-means implementation but i'm struggling to decide when should i stop searching for K. I'm following Chapter 5 of the Advanced analytics with Spark book.

Also, when i'm trying different values from K, my dataset is distributed only in 3 of the clusters at most, even when my value of k is bigger than 200.

My dataset has 10 categorical values and 5 numeric values, i transform each categorical value to a numeric id value.

Can any one give me some tips on what to do or how to validate my results?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that you only get 3 clusters for different values of k? You should get exactly k clusters. Also, you should standardize your data in a more meaningful way, given that you have categorical variables have a look at Gower distance. To find the best k you can use the tGap statistic or the "elbow" method using variance explained.

Comment: I get exactly k clusters, but when i predict using my initial data it is distributed in only 3 clusters and the rest have 0 ocurrences. Thanks for the tips! i'll look into Gower distance.

I'm also trying to use the elbow method with normalized data, but my graph tends to go like the image

https://imgur.com/a/0vAXYRf

Comment: @RubénFigueredo Two options: 1) either the clusters formed during training do not really exist, they are just random noise from building too many clusters, or 2) your test set is not representative of the population, like your training set is. First option is more likely. Graphs that are very flat like yours in the elbow method usually mean that there is too much noise in the data, that is the model cannot really identify any good candidates / clusters